# For loop gives two answers for same query

Tags: php, laravel

I couldn't understand why for loop gives two answers for same queries.

For for Loop as follows,

```
for($i=1; $i<=$packcount; $i++)
            {
                $user->trees()->create([
                    'tin' => $settings->settings_value++, // Starts at 1000
                    'validity' => 1,
                ]);

                $settings->settings_value = $settings->settings_value++;
                $settings->save();
            }

// $packcount = 3
```

While executing, $b gives us 1002 and $d gives as 1003. Why is this ?

Please do let me know if am doing anything wrong.

Comment: You are incrementing the same object.  Otherwise, you do a `clone`. I'm sure there is a duplicate page here that does an eloquent job of explaining this.  Volunteers, please help me to find it.

Comment: When you assign `$settings->settings_value` to each variable you are just passing it as a reference, hence when you increment `$d` the `$b` also gets incremented.

Comment: I refactored, still i get the same output

Comment: Can you please check now @Presmelito